# Copy images from flash drive when inserted

Tags: python, script

I would like to automatically copy the contents of a USB flash drive to the internal storage of the Pi whenever I insert the flash drive into one of the Pi's USB ports.

I have set up a python script to handle the copying:

```
import os
from shutil import copyfile, ignore_patterns

source = '/media/pi/4DD7-393F/'
files = os.listdir(source)

dest = '/home/pi/Desktop/slideshow/photo_frames/daniel/images/'

for file in files:
    if file.endswith(('ANI', 'BMP', 'CAL', 'FAX', 'GIF', 'IMG', 'JBG', 'JPE', 'JPEG', 'JPG',
   'jpg', 'MAC', 'PBM', 'PCD', 'PCX', 'PCT', 'PGM', 'PNG', 'PPM', 'PSD', 'RAS','TGA', 'TIFF', 'WMF')):
    copyfile(source + file, dest + file)
```

When run from terminal with `python /home/pi/Desktop/slideshow/photo_frames/daniel/usb_copy.py` the script functions as expected - files with the corresponding extensions are copied into the appropriate destination folder.

In an attempt to automate this process upon my inserting the flash drive, I tried creating a udev rule.  To do so, I obtained identifying information for my flash drive using `udevadm info /dev/sda1` and received the following:

```
P: /devices/platform/soc/3f980000.usb/usb1/1-1/1-1.4/1-1.4:1.0/host8/target8:0:0/8:0:0:0/block/sda/sda1
N: sda1
S: disk/by-id/usb-Kingston_DataTraveler_2.0_50E549C20280EE61B98F0011-0:0-part1
S: disk/by-path/platform-3f980000.usb-usb-0:1.4:1.0-scsi-0:0:0:0-part1
S: disk/by-uuid/4DD7-393F
E: DEVLINKS=/dev/disk/by-id/usb-Kingston_DataTraveler_2.0_50E549C20280EE61B98F0011-0:0-part1 /dev/disk/by-path/platform-3f980000.usb-usb-0:1.4:1.0-scsi-0:0:0:0-part1 /dev/disk/by-uuid/4DD7-393F
E: DEVNAME=/dev/sda1
E: DEVPATH=/devices/platform/soc/3f980000.usb/usb1/1-1/1-1.4/1-1.4:1.0/host8/target8:0:0/8:0:0:0/block/sda/sda1
E: DEVTYPE=partition
E: ID_BUS=usb
E: ID_DRIVE_THUMB=1
E: ID_FS_TYPE=vfat
E: ID_FS_USAGE=filesystem
E: ID_FS_UUID=4DD7-393F
E: ID_FS_UUID_ENC=4DD7-393F
E: ID_FS_VERSION=FAT32
E: ID_INSTANCE=0:0
E: ID_MODEL=DataTraveler_2.0
E: ID_MODEL_ENC=DataTraveler\x202.0
E: ID_MODEL_ID=6545
E: ID_PART_ENTRY_DISK=8:0
E: ID_PART_ENTRY_NUMBER=1
E: ID_PART_ENTRY_OFFSET=2
E: ID_PART_ENTRY_SCHEME=dos
E: ID_PART_ENTRY_SIZE=60978814
E: ID_PART_ENTRY_TYPE=0xc
E: ID_PART_TABLE_TYPE=dos
E: ID_PATH=platform-3f980000.usb-usb-0:1.4:1.0-scsi-0:0:0:0
E: ID_PATH_TAG=platform-3f980000_usb-usb-0_1_4_1_0-scsi-0_0_0_0
E: ID_REVISION=PMAP
E: ID_SERIAL=Kingston_DataTraveler_2.0_50E549C20280EE61B98F0011-0:0
E: ID_SERIAL_SHORT=50E549C20280EE61B98F0011
E: ID_TYPE=disk
E: ID_USB_DRIVER=usb-storage
E: ID_USB_INTERFACES=:080650:
E: ID_USB_INTERFACE_NUM=00
E: ID_VENDOR=Kingston
E: ID_VENDOR_ENC=Kingston
E: ID_VENDOR_ID=0930
E: MAJOR=8
E: MINOR=1
E: SUBSYSTEM=block
E: TAGS=:systemd:
E: USEC_INITIALIZED=18625356
```

In my `/etc/udev/rules.d/` folder, I have created a file, `100-mydevice.rules` and it contains:

```
ACTION=="add", ATTRS{idVendor}=="0930", ATTRS{idProduct}=="6545" RUN+="python /home/pi/Desktop/slideshow/photo_frames/daniel/usb_copy.py"
```

When I insert the flash drive, the script does not run - at least, the files are not copied properly.  Any information regarding how to fix this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Try running `sudo udevadm trigger --verbose` and `sudo udevadm control --reload-rules`. Also, make sure you have rebooted the machine.